# Find axial intercepts of a perpendicular plane of vector [xyz], the plane passing through its position [x,y,z]

Tags: vectors, solid-geometry, cross-sections

I tried to make the question as brief as possible in the title without omitting critical aspects.

There are three elements to it.

1) A position vector [xyz] is given first and then

2) Its perpendicular plane must go through position [xyz], and

3) Lastly find the intercepts the plane makes with the XYZ axes

The vectors coming in are arbitrary, but we may restrict them to positive quadrant of the coordinate axes in the answer.

With that quadrant restriction the plane completes a solid triangle with the intercepts forming the base corners, and origin the apex corner. But in my case the intercepts may be any length so long as constraints [1] [2] are met.

I have not found a standard procedure out there (yet)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you have the equation of the plane in the form $ax+by+cz=d$, then the axis intercepts are $-d/a$, $-d/b$ and $-d/c$, respectively. If any of the denominators is zero, then the plane is, of course, parallel to that axis.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that my data did not begin with that equation but only with the original 'positional' vector. But your posting is useful in that it speeds up the unpacking of intercepts once it is found. I also followed R.A.Tanuharja's procedure symbolically and found out that in my particular problem your 'd' here equals the spherical parameter a^2+b^2+c^2, which means the intercepts can be uncovered very quickly in two short steps. Thank you too!

Answer (score 2):

I assume You are referring to a plane which pass through a point and is perpendicular to that point’s position vector.

If the point we were talking about is $\vec{r_{0}}$, then the plane is $\vec{r_{0}}\cdot\left(\vec{r_{0}}-\vec{r}\right)=0$.

To find intercept with $x$ - axis, simply make $\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$ component of $\vec{r}$ as zero and try to find its $\hat{i}$ component. For $y$ and $z$ axis, i am sure you can manage now. I will give an example below.

## Example

Find a plane passing through $(1,2,3)$ and is perpendicular to its position vector, then find its intercept with the axes.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(1\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+3\hat{k}\right)\cdot\left((1-x)\hat{i}+(2-y)\hat{j}+(3-z)\hat{k}\right)&=0\\
1-x+4-2y+9-3z&=0\\
14&=x+2y+3z
\end{aligned}
$$

To find intercept with $x$ axis, set $y=z=0$

$$
14=x
$$

To find intercept with $y$ and $z$ axes, similar

$$
\begin{aligned}
14&=2y\\
7&=y\\
\\
14&=3z\\
\frac{14}{3}&=z
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Exactly what I was fumbling for over two days. Many thanks!

Comment: I now realize the perpendicular plane at the position vector is the tangent of the sphere of its length as radius. That geometric fact does not jump out naturally from the vector treatment. But thanks for adding that insight to me.